# Find a generating function for $a_r = n^3$

Tags: combinatorics

What is the generating function for $a_r = n^3$? I computed an answer, just wanted to double check my answer.

Comment: What did you find? Also do you mean $a_r = r^3$?

Comment: You want that somebody check your solution, but you don't show it.

Comment: It is:  $\frac{x + 4x^2 + x^3}{(1 - x)^4} = \frac{6}{(1 - x)^4} - \frac{12}{(1 - x)^3} + \frac{7}{(1 - x)^2} - \frac{1}{1 - x}$.

Comment: You can use Wolfram Alpha to check if a gf is correct.  Just type in "power series" and your function, for example, and check if the coefficients are what you want.

Comment: I tried but I wasn't able to do it. Can you give me an example of what the input form into Wolfram Apha would be like?

Comment: Sure, just try "(x + 4x^2 + x^3)/(1-x)^4 power series" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you advance. Assume

$$ F(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a_r x^r \implies F(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} r^3 x^r $$

$$ \implies F(x)= (xD)(xD)(xD)\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} x^r = (xD)^3 \frac{1}{1-x}, $$

where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$.

Can you finished now?

**Added** Here is the final answer

> $$ F(x)={\frac {x \left( 1+4\,x+{x}^{2} \right) }{ \left( 1-x \right) ^{4}}}. $$

Comment: That is what I did. I got the answer that is shown above. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that you want the operator $(xD)^3$, as $r$ is only an index within the sum.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Yes. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's the same result I got. Thank you for help.

Comment: @gandolf: Good job. You are welcome.